# CakePhp 3.0 : PDO issues

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, pdo

I am currently working on CakePHP 3.0 and I am meeting issues while connecting to my database.

To resume :

> Your version of PHP is 5.4.16 or higher.
>
> Your version of PHP has the mbstring extension loaded.
>
> Your version of PHP has the openssl extension loaded.
>
> Your version of PHP has the intl extension loaded.

Then :

> Your tmp directory is writable.
>
> Your logs directory is writable.
>
> The FileEngine is being used for core caching. To change the config
>   edit config/app.php

But :

> CakePHP is NOT able to connect to the database.
>
> Connection to database could not be established: SQLSTATE[HY000]
>   [2006] MySQL server has gone away

The warning that I have are :

> Warning (2): PDO::__construct(): MySQL server has gone away
>   [CORE\src\Database\Driver\PDODriverTrait.php, line 48] Warning (2):
>   PDO::__construct() [pdo.construct]: Error while reading greeting
>   packet. PID=25748 [CORE\src\Database\Driver\PDODriverTrait.php, line
>   48]

My PDODriverTrait.php on line 48 is :

```
protected function _connect($dsn, array $config)
{
    $connection = new PDO(
        $dsn,
        $config['username'],
        $config['password'],
        $config['flags']
    );
    $this->connection($connection);
    return true;
}
```

And my app.php Datasources is :

```
 'className' => 'Cake\Database\Connection',
    'driver' => 'Cake\Database\Driver\Mysql',
    'persistent' => false,
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'port' => '81',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'database' => 'projetatelier',
    'encoding' => 'utf8',
    'timezone' => 'UTC',
    'cacheMetadata' => true,
    'quoteIdentifiers' => false,
```

I checked my PDO extensions and all seems to be correct.

Thanks

Comment: try to remove port part and check. Also what is $config['flags']?

Comment: Marien please up-vote the answer also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your code that you show,The problem are:-

1. Either your MySQL is working on some other port so just put that port number in your app.php.
2. Or port number need to remove form the file app.php.

First try to remove it and try. if not working then check on which port MySQL is working and then put this value in port rather than 80.